# How to select max / distinct record in MySQL using a deleted_at column

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I am trying to select distinct rows under the following two rules:

- If its deleted_at date is null then it is the most recent record, select it
- If it is the latest deleted_at date (and there's not a record with a NULL), it is also the most recent record, select it

Consider this table:

[image]

The result I am looking for would be:

[image]

I'm using MySQL mariaDB v10.1.33 which does not have all the functions I am use to.

NULL was being ignored so I use a 
`coalesce(fc.deleted_at, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())` 
to trick it into being the latest date. That way I can use max() function to select it. However, when I use this it is mismatching the data in the rows! i.e. this:

```
SELECT max(coalesce(fc.deleted_at, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())), folder_id, code 
FROM folder_code fc 
WHERE fc.folder_id = 5683
```

returns:

[image]

I did some reading and this is a common problem where it seems to be ordering and selecting the max of each column independent of the row it is associated with and there are suggestions to use group by and order by to overcome it. However when I do this I get the same result i.e. this also returns the same as above:

```
SELECT max(coalesce(fc.deleted_at, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())) as maxdeleteddate, fc.folder_id, fc.code
FROM folder_code fc
WHERE fc.folder_id = 5683
GROUP BY fc.folder_id 
ORDER BY maxdeleteddate desc
```

How to I achieve my desired result?

Thank you

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: out of curiosity, what is the primary key of that table? if you had one, it would make this a lot easier...

Comment: also, you seem to want the max `deleted_at` value *grouped by folder_id* - if that's the case, please clarify you question

Comment: @billynoah this table does not have a primary key which is frustrating otherwise I could do it. Yes that's correct I want the max deleted_at value grouped by folder_id to get the latest code

Comment: what is the datatype of your `deleted_at` column?  It doesn't appear to be `datetime`...

Comment: @billynoah datetime, 2019-02-04 15:40:04 is the value. The copy paste screenshot converted it's format.

Comment: This is exactly why screenshots of tables are a bad idea in questions here.  In the future post schema and real table data, and consider creating a fiddle somewhere like: http://sqlfiddle.com/

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it:

```
SELECT f1.*
FROM folder f1
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT folder_id,
            NULLIF(MAX(IF(deleted_at IS NULL,NOW(),deleted_at)),NOW()) AS deleted_at
        FROM folder
        GROUP BY folder_id
    ) f2 ON f2.folder_id = f1.folder_id AND f2.deleted_at <=> f1.deleted_at
```

And here's a fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wzCYktpavBNnJu2uejPpe9/1

The idea is to get the groupwise-max, then join your table against itself.  If you simply group the rows, you are not guaranteed to get the correct values for non-aggregated columns.

There is also a trick with `deleted_at` column, using `NOW()` if it's null, then using `NULLIF()` to set it back to `NULL` for the join.

This approach also benefits from the fact that it potentially uses indexes if they exist.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL 8+, then you may use `ROW_NUMBER` here:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY folder_id
                                 ORDER BY -ISNULL(deleted_at), deleted_at DESC) rn
    FROM folder_code
)

SELECT folder_id, code, deleted_at
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

[image]

### Demo

The `ORDER BY` clause used in the call to `ROW_NUMBER` places all records having a `NULL` deletion date after those records have a date, for each group of `folder_id` records.  Then, the second level of sorting places more recent deletion date records first.  This means that for those folders have a `NULL` record, it would appear first, otherwise the most recent record would appear first.

Here is an old school solution which might also work:

```
SELECT f1.folder_id, f1.code, f1.deleted_at
FROM folder_code f1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT folder_id,
        CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = COUNT(deleted_at)
             THEN MAX(deleted_at) END AS max_deleted_at
    FROM folder_code
    GROUP BY folder_id
) f2
    ON f1.folder_id = f2.folder_id AND
       (f1.deleted_at = f2.max_deleted_at OR
           (f1.deleted_at IS NULL AND f2.max_deleted_at IS NULL));
```

### Demo

Comment: I am using v10.1.33-MariaDB however it seems to have an issue with your query. I'm having trouble getting it to run it. It's throwing an error on the PARTITION BY. Looks like i need v10.2 to use ROW_NUMBER().

Comment: @SSS You might want to upgrade, as `ROW_NUMBER` is a very useful thing to have.

Comment: I wish I could though this DB is an ancient managed service that I have no control over. I only have read access to query it.

Comment: @SSS I have given you a workaround query which should be usable on your version of MariaDB.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below - using correlated subquery

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=f1da51c41c979a96deacdfddd64fafad)**

```
select * from t1 a 
    where coalesce(deleted_at,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) =
     (select max(coalesce(deleted_at,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())) from t1 a1 where a.folder_id=a1.folder_id)
```

OUTPUT:

```
older_id    code    deleted_at
5333        12VA1   2019-09-27
5683        12SR1-X
```

Comment: Thank you though this returns both rows. I see where you are coming at thinking the case statement is needed though the coalesce is ok.

Comment: You might want to use some timestamp way in the future just to be safe.

Comment: This had me confused for a moment. Usually we use `EXISTS` with correlated subqueries and `IN` with non-correlated ones. In this query it should be neither of the two. Use `=` instead.

Answer (score 0):

One way to get the latest date is to make sure there is no later date. Your approach to replace NULL with a high date is good and can be used for this.

```
select *
from folder_code fc
where not exists
(
  select *
  from folder_code fc2
  where fc2.folder_id = fc.folder_id
  and coalesce(fc2.deleted_at, date '9999-12-31') > coalesce(fc.deleted_at, date '9999-12-31')
);
```